# How to set neovim's lua module search path?

Tags: neovim

I found a very useful file browsing plugin: [nvim-tree](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua)

But I think this plugin can also add a template function to create files using templates.

I'd like to develop this functionality myself, but I'm running into a plugin debugging problem.

I want to use the original functionality of this plugin before the new functionality is developed. I have installed it via [packer.vim](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim).

I forked it on github and cloned it to `/hom/user/Project/nvim-tree.lua`.

I found that every time I want to debug this plugin, lua's require function will always look for modules from `/home/user/.local/share/nvim` and will not use my modified modules.

How can I solve this problem?

I have very little experience with neovim or vim plugin development, especially about debugging. If you can teach me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

***tl;dr***

Try cloning the project to `~/.config/nvim/lua/nvim-tree.lua`.  Then you should be able to require it as `require('nvim-tree')`.

***explanation***

If you run `:echo &runtimepath` you will see the full list of directories that nvim will search for runtime files (run `:help 'runtimepath` for more information).  Neovim will search in order from left to right.  The first by default should be `~/.config/nvim`.  By placing the plugin there you are short circuiting your package manager, since your plugin manager will (by default) be placing plugins in `~/.local/{site,share}`.

Neovim has a helpful resource on getting started with Lua in Neovim [here](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua-guide.html).  The Lua [docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) on `require` are also helpful but keep in mind that the lookup path in Neovim is slightly different (Neovim has a custom built-in Lua implementation).